# Why is window creation slow for many windows? Can it be faster?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, window

For an experiment I want to create lots of small windows. I mean a lot, like a thousand or so.

The windows are small, containing some labels only (AB):

[image]

I created a hundred of them as an experiment, but their display is not instantaneous, it is visible as they are put on the screen. Why is that?

I expected for a C/C++ program to be very fast, so that I don't see the windows put on the screen at all. Is it a wrong expectation? Or should I use some kind of lighter window type (I'm no Windows-programmer, so I'm just guessing) which can be put up much faster?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
   HWND parent = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
   {
       HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_BORDER,
           CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

       if (!hWnd)
       {
           return FALSE;
       }

       if (parent == 0)
           parent = hWnd;
       else
           SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT, (long)parent);

       SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0);
       SetMenu(hWnd, NULL);
       SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, 100 + (i * 20), 100, 20, 20, 0);
       ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
       UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   }

...

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0));
            TextOut(hdc, 1, 1, TEXT("AB"), strlen("AB"));

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Calling `UpdateWindow` forces each window to be painted before the next one is created. If you take that out they might appear faster.

Comment: I commented it out, but it didn't make it faster.

Comment: What other tasks/processes are running?

Comment: In the program? Nothing. This is all it does. My CPU is at 4%.

Comment: I don't see why would one expect a hundred of windows to be created instantaneously. There are some pretty heavy things happening under the hood.

Comment: This program is highly non-idiomatic. It creates top-level windows (no WS_CHILD) but then sets their parent (GWL_HWNDPARENT), which is a confusing "neither nor" case that is going to cause problems. Furthermore, you create a chain of nested windows 100 levels deep, which is also not something normal programs do.

Comment: @Eugene Sh  why not? Surely it's not such a big task for a computer today, that I should see it

Comment: @Raymond Chen I'm no windows programmer, I only added the parent stuff to avoid creating a hundred icons on the taskbar. It's not instaneous without it either.

Comment: Each window is a complex object, consisting of other objects. Creating one requires allocating a bunch of different resources. And all this work is usually done through several layers of abstraction. Not speaking of the fact that OS has other things to do in parallel. So no, I don't think it is such a simple task for even a modern computer.

Comment: By he way.. Do you have windows animation enabled? This will give you the impression that these are created slowly.

Comment: I turned off animations, but the result is the same. If windows cannot be put faster then this implementation was the wrong idea for my experiment. I'll think of something else. E.g. creating one transparent window covering the screen and putting a thousand labels in it at various positions.  That may be faster than creating many windows.

Comment: What's your goal? You can try creating the windows but not showing them. Then show them in a separate loop. That might make it visually faster.

Comment: My goal is to show these labels (AB) instantaneously. Precreating the windows and showing them only when they are ready is a good idea. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: All you need is a *single* transparent window (using key-color transparency). There is no reason to create a window for each label; you can simply render those onto the transparent window, thereby removing the transparency in those areas, that do not match the key-color. Toggling visibility of the overlay boils down to a single call to `ShowWindow`. This is going to be instantaneous.

Answer (score 2):

`SetWindowLong`, `SetMenu`, `SetWindowPos` and `ShowWindow` can all be removed by giving the same information in the `CreateWindowW` arguments.

Then you can also remove the call to `UpdateWindow`.

Here its not the speed of C/C++ that matter, but the Win32 API calls which send windows messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it when I figure out how to do the same things with parameters.